# Could not find com.android.tools.build:transform-api:1.5.0.?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to make a plugin using transform to do some bytecode manipulation, but I met this problem when I'm trying to use it:

[image]

but I've registered the transform in my method and add it to the dependency in the gradle file, I dont understand why this happens?

this is the stack trace:
[image]

Comment: You are missing the `google()` repository

Comment: So I found out that in the noted directory transform-api:1.5.0 doesn't exist however 2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api exisits, I tried replacing 1.5.0 directly with 2.0.0 but didnt work, and a new problem occurred, still trying to figure out the solution

Comment: goole() should be in top level, this gradle file is for plugin

Comment: You still need repositories for where to pull plugin dependencies

Comment: in case you dont have the latest gradle, you should try this `maven { url "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/" }`, same as `google()`